# find the locus of the centroid of a triangle whose vertices are $(a \cos t, a \sin t), (b \sin t, -b \cos t)$ & $(1,0)$

Tags: geometry

I got a question to find the locus of the centroid of a triangle whose vertices are $(a \cos t, a \sin t), (b \sin t, -b \cos t)$ & $(1,0) $.

The answer is $(3x-1)^2+9^2=a^2+b^2$

Thank you in advance:)

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*

$G=(x,y)=(\frac{a\cos(t)+b\sin(t) + 1}{3},\frac{a\sin(t) -b\cos(t) }{3})$

So you have a system of equations:
$\begin{cases}x=\frac{a\cos(t)+b\sin(t) + 1}{3} \\ y=\frac{a\sin(t) -b\cos(t) }{3} \end{cases}$

Find $\sin(t)$ and $cos(t)$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ and then use $sin^2(t)+cos^2(t)=1$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$M_1:=\left(\frac{a\cos t+1}2\;,\;\frac{a\sin t}2\right)\\
M_2:=\left(\frac{b\sin t+1}2\;,\;\frac{-b\cos t}2\right)$$

Now just find the intersection point of the lines $\;l_1\;,\;l_2\;$ , where $\;l_1\;$ passes through $\;(b\sin t,-b\cos t) \;,\;M_1\;$ , and $\;l_2\; $ passes through $\;(a\cos t,a\sin t)\;,\;M_2\;$

Comment: what are M1 and M2?

Comment: Ah, good question @gaurav. Check them carefully and remember your basic analytic geometry...and think: what dio we want to achieve here?